# reference request: voltage in a resistor network is a unique harmonic function

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

An undirected graph may be regarded as a resistor network where each edge corresponds to a resistor of unit resistance. This paper covers such an approach.

- [*On electric resistances for distance-regular graphs*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2810) by Jack Koolen, Greg Markowsky, and Jongyook Park

I paraphrase some statements from Chapter 3 of this paper.

---

Consider a graph $G$ as a resistor network where each edge is a unit resistance. 
To compute the effective resistance between two vertices $u$ and $v$, assume that a battery of voltage $V$ is attached to $u$ and $v$ producing a current through the graph.
The current flowing through the circuit can be determined by calculating the voltage at each point on the graph.
A function $f$ on the vertex set $V$ of $G$ is **harmonic** at a point $z\in V$ if $f(z)$ is the average of neighboring values of f; that is,
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{\text{for any $x$ adjacent to $z$}}\big(f(x)-f(z)\big) = 0.
\end{equation*}
The voltage function on V can be characterized as the *unique* function which is harmonic on $V − \{u, v\}$ having the prescribed values on $u$ and $v$.

---

I'd like to use this characterization on my research. But I cannot find a reference for this 'harmonic characterization' on any other textbook. Even the above paper doesn't cite any reference for this statement. I skim through many graph theory textbooks (such as Bollobas) but in vain.

Is this characterization true? Which textbooks or papers can I use as a reference?

Comment: Kemeny and Snell: Denumerable Markov Chains?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Doyle and Snell is probably an easier read.

Comment: @IgorRivin: I think that is the book that I was thinking of.

Comment: Nice question. But be careful: see https://xkcd.com/356/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am reading correctly, this appears as Theorem 1.15 of Geoffrey Grimmett's book *Probability on Graphs*.

It is available for free on [Grimmett's web site](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~grg/books/USpgs-rev3.pdf) and has also been [published by Cambridge University Press](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/statistics-probability/probability-theory-and-stochastic-processes/probability-graphs-random-processes-graphs-and-lattices?format=PB&isbn=9780521147354).

Answer (score 3):

My prefered reference for the subject is David's Wagner lecture notes:

https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~dgwagner/Networks.pdf

Answer (score 1):

"Random walks and electric networks" by Doyle and Snell is where I learned it. I'm glad if you found our paper interesting.

Comment: Actually I could use some help on a fragment of a paper I have on this topic. If you (or anyone else) is working on electric resistance and random walks on graphs, and is interested to hear about the project, please drop me a line (just google me to find email address).